# IIS не понимает символ & при использовании среды NET. Framework 4

Tags: iis

Есть открытая директория (папка) на сервере, которая содержит другие папки с символом &, при попытке открыть любую папку с таким сиволом получаем ошибку 400 - плохой запрос. Если же использовать среду NET. Framework 2.*, то таких проблем не возникает.

В журнале событий:

```
Код события: 3005 
Сообщение о событии: Возникло необработанное исключение. 

Сведения об исключении: 
    Тип исключения: HttpException 
    Сообщение об исключении: Обнаружено потенциально опасное значение Request.Path, полученное от клиента (&).
   в System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()
   в System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context)
```

Каким образом можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967103/a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client